# Can't access uuid field in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rails-migrations

I have a table called 'products' (model is Product) and I can't access the :uuid attribute when running in migration context. The migration itself does not change the structure but accesses and creates new objects to populate the DB.

This is a snippet of the schema.rb prior to the migration:

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "price"
    t.uuid     "uuid"
  end
```

The Product object is defined as follows:

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
```

Now when running in rails console / code this works fine:

```
p = Product.create!(:uuid => xxx)
puts p.uuid # => xxx
puts p.inspect # => Product(title: string, description: string, price: string, uuid: uuid)
```

**However while running in the migration context - the same code raises an exception:**

```
p = Product.create!(:uuid => xxx)
puts p.uuid # => undefined method `uuid' for <Product:0x007fea6d7aa058>/opt/rubies/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433
puts p.inspect # => Product(title: string, description: string, price: string)
```

**The uuid attribute is missing! What's wrong?**

Comment: Could you post the whole migration file?

Comment: Are you are using `PostgreSQL >= 9.4`?

Comment: @BroiStatse Hmm.. I would do that but unfortunately it contains too much private code

Comment: @pavan Yes, as a matter of fact we are on Postgres 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
Product.reset_column_information
```

before your `Product.create` line.

Comment: You got the "right answer" for being the first! Close call :)

Answer (score 1):

The schema of the model is generally refreshed after the migration. Therefore, even if the `uuid` field is created, the model doesn't have knowledge of it yet.

You can force a refresh by using

```
Product.reset_column_information
```

However, the issue in your code reveals you are probably using the migration feature to create records inside the migration itself. This is generally not recommended as the migrations are designed to change the schema of your database, not the data.

You should use create a specific rake task to modify the data and run the task after the migration is completed, for example from the console.

Comment: We indeed use those migrations to populate default configurations etc. I know this isn't technically part of the DB structure but it's very handy...

Comment: Regardless of that, your plan sounds interesting and I may learn something new... so (1) how do you do that automatically in CI systems? and (2) how do you keep this code from breaking in future releases where the models' code changes? We currently solve both problems by setting up temporary classes IN the migrations to match the current state of the DB